# Use "theme" in Tailwind plugin

Tags: javascript, typescript, tailwind-css

There is a simple plugin. How can I call variables from the theme? Tried like this:

```
/** @type {Plugin} */
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin');

module.exports = plugin(function ({ addBase, theme }) {
  return addBase({
    '.test-1': {color: 'green'}, // it works
    '.test-2': theme('colors.amber.300') // doesn't work
  });
});
```

Comment: Because `theme()` retruns some value (in your case color) not CSS property-value pair (`{color: color}`). It should be `'.test-2': {color: theme('colors.amber.300'})`

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka thanks. Can you tell me if it is possible to use the previous setted styles?  like that - ```'.test-2': theme('test.1')```